# Array of Images-Getting the same errors

Tags: processing

Whenever I write this code:

```
PImage[] flowers=new PImage[3];
Bubble[] bubbles=new Bubble[5];

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  for(int i=0; i<flowers.length; i++){
    flowers[i]=loadImage(“flower”+i+".jpg");
  }
  for(int i=0; i<bubbles.length; i++){
    int index=int(random(0,flowers.length));
    bubbles[i]=new Bubble(flowers[index],100+i*100, 300, random(32, 72));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i=0; i<bubbles.length; i++){
    bubbles[i].display();
    bubbles[i].ascend();
    bubbles[i].top();
  }
}

AND CLASS:
class Bubble {
  float x;
  float y;
  float diameter;
  PImage img;

  Bubble(PImage tempImg, float tempX, float tempY, float tempD) {
    x=tempX;
    y=tempY;
    diameter=tempD;
    img=tempImg;
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(127);
    image(img,x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }

  void ascend() {
    y–;
    x=x+random(-2, 2);
  }

  void top() {
    if (y<diameter/2) {
      y=diameter/2;
    }
  }
}
```

I ALWAYS get errors saying ‘‘The file “flower0.jpg” is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file “flower1.jpg” is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file “flower2.jpg” is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
NullPointerException
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
For more information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting.’’

Even though I have doubled checked on how and where I saved the images (name etc) I still can’t get past this.

Comment: Where is the image in relation to the path that your executable is running. I'm not sure whether that will search for the image in the path your executable is running, or if it will default to "C:\". it is best to have the full path to the image so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: the path class has many methods to assist with file processing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Processing has a very easy way to let you access local files without worrying about the path too much. In the sketch's folder, create a `data` folder, and put your images in there.

Here's an example with an image file named "hexa.png":

[image: hexa.png is in the data folder]

Your code will want 3 images, `flower0.jpg`, `flower1.jpg` and `flower2.jpg`. If you set up your sketch like I just showed you, things should run smoothly (assuming that the rest of the sketch is in working order).

Have fun!

Comment: I did just like you said and I still get the same errors. Was there supposed to be a data folder before I actually make one myself?

Comment: It's fine if you add it yourself, and it should find the images in the data folder. The issue us the line I told you to fix: this was a mistake (and I'm going to edit it out of the answer). I have to specify "data/" _to save the file there_ and I didn't notice that in that sketch I was saving instead of just loading. Try it again with `flowers[i]=loadImage(“flower”+i+".jpg");` and it'll find the images.

Comment: turns out the file extension was hidden in win10 so I kept adding .jpg twice!

Answer (score 0):

turns out the file extension was hidden in win10 so I kept adding .jpg twice